# Scrapy Python loop to next unscraped link

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm trying to make my spider go over a list and scrape all the url's it can find following them scraping some data and returning to continue on the next unscraped link if i run the spider i can see that it returns back to the starting page but tries to scrape the same page again and just quits afterwards any code suggestions pretty new to python.

```
import scrapy
import re
from production.items import ProductionItem, ListResidentialItem

class productionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "production"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://domain.com/list"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
            item = ProductionItem()
            item['listurl'] = sel.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract()[0]

            request = scrapy.Request(item['listurl'], callback=self.parseBasicListingInfo)
            yield request

    def parseBasicListingInfo(item, response):
        item = ListResidentialItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="detail"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

to clarify: 
i'm passing [0] so it only takes the first link of the list
but i want it to continue using the next unscraped link

output after running the spider :

```
2016-07-18 12:11:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.domain.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-18 12:11:20 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.domain.com/list> (referer: None)
2016-07-18 12:11:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.domain.com/link1> (referer: http://www.domain.com/list)
2016-07-18 12:11:21 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.domain.com/link1>
{'title': [u'\rlink1\r']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work fine. Change the domain and xpath and see

```
    import scrapy
    import re
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

    class ProdItems(scrapy.Item):
        listurl = scrapy.Field()
        title = scrapy.Field()

    class productionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "production"
        allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
        start_urls = [
            "http://domain.com/list"
        ]

        def parse(self, response):
            for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
                item = ProductionItem()
                list_urls = sel.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract()
                for url in list_urls:
                  item['listurl'] = url
                  yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parseBasicListingInfo,  meta={'item': item})

        def parseBasicListingInfo(item, response):
            item = response.request.meta['item']
            item['title'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="detail"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: the code executes but so did mine the problem of looping over the scraped links still remains

Comment: @user1443063 `http://domain.com/list` gives me 404 is this the page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: oh no this is not the exact website i've changed most of the personal scraping information, i'm just looking how to loop over all the links it finds

Comment: See if you remove the `item['listurl'] = sel.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract()[0]` `[0]` from this you will get the list of all matching urls and then on that list you can run a `for` loop

Comment: but everytime i pass a list to request = scrapy.Request(item['listurl'], callback=self.parseBasicListingInfo) i get an error stating i can only pas a string and no lists to the callback function

Comment: oh now i see how it works thank you both for helping out

Comment: The outer for loop is completely redundant as I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that's causing your problem:

```
item['listurl'] = sel.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract()[0]
```

The "//" means "from the start of the document" which means that it scans from the very first tag and will always find the same first link. What you need to do is search relative to the start of the current tag using ".//" which means "from this tag onwards". Also your current for loop is visiting every tag in the document which is unneccesary. Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract():
        item = ProductionItem()
        item['listurl'] = href

        yield scrapy.Request(href,callback=self.parseBasicListingInfo,  meta={'item': item})
```

The xpath pulls the hrefs out of the links and returns them as a list you can iterate over.

Comment: so i tried using the code sample you gave and tried to pass :
response.xpath('//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract():
aswell as response.xpath('.//a[@id="link101"]/@href').extract():
but it still only outputs only the first link it finds

Comment: Have you tried to run scrapy with --loglevel=DEBUG? That should show every URL that gets queued by the Request call. Also try the xpath using something like Firebug for Firefox. Also try `scrapy shell`. And as @Nikhil Parmar points out domain.com/list gets a 404 error.

Comment: added the console output it just grinds to a halt after the first link

Comment: That's because your code was yielding the same request multple times and scrapy has a built in filter to ignore dupliate Requests().